# moment(new Date().toISOString() always returns the same date and time

Tags: node.js, mongodb, insert, timestamp

I am trying to use  moment(new Date().toISOString() in mongoose model
as shown below

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var uniqueValidator = require('mongoose-unique-validator');
  Schema = mongoose.Schema;


var moment = require('moment');

//  https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-unique-validator
var categorySchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
      CatId:{ type: Number, required: true, unique: true },
      Name : { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
      Description : String,
      Is_Active:Number,
      Db_Created_TimeStamp:{type:Date,default: moment(new Date().toISOString())},
      Db_Updated_TimeStamp:{type:Date,default:moment(new Date().toISOString())},
  },{collection: "Categories"})
categorySchema.plugin(uniqueValidator);
mongoose.model('Categories',categorySchema);
```

when data is inserted in the mongodb always it is showing the same time

Not sure whether i am missing some thing

The idea of doing it is getting the time stamp including millisecond

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a163a14ed910b1279d7ca3f"), 
    "Is_Active" : NumberInt(1), 
    "Description" : "spo22rt", 
    "Name" : "spo22rt", 
    "CatId" : NumberInt(2), 
    "Db_Updated_TimeStamp" : ***ISODate("2017-11-23T03:01:25.349+0000"), 
    "Db_Created_TimeStamp" : ISODate("2017-11-23T03:01:25.346+0000"),*** 
    "__v" : NumberInt(0)
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a163a2ced910b1279d7ca40"), 
    "Is_Active" : NumberInt(1), 
    "Description" : "spossss22rt", 
    "Name" : "spo22rsst", 
    "CatId" : NumberInt(1), 
    "Db_Updated_TimeStamp" : **ISODate("2017-11-23T03:01:25.349+0000"), 
    "Db_Created_TimeStamp" : ISODate("2017-11-23T03:01:25.346+0000"), 
    "__v" : NumberInt(0)**
}
```

Here the first record i have inserted is having time 2017-11-23T03:01:25.349+0000

After 3 minutes i inserted the second record but still same time in db

2017-11-23T03:01:25.349+0000

I am trying this insertion at 8:40AM
but i am not sure what is that time 03:01:25

I am missing something fundamentals i think almost spent a day to understand but no clue to understand what is happening please help me in understanding this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the `default` is set to a value, the value will be set when the app starts up and it first `require` the schema. In this case, the default value becomes the value of `new Date().toISOString()` when the app starts up.

Set the `default` to a function, so the function runs and returns the current date whenever a new model instance is created.

```
  Db_Created_TimeStamp: {
    type: Date,
    default: ()=> new Date().toISOString()
  },
  Db_Updated_TimeStamp: {
    type: Date,
    default: ()=> new Date().toISOString()
  },
```

Mongoose does provide the fields for "free" with the [`timestamps` option](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#timestamps):

```
var thingSchema = new Schema({..}, { timestamps: { createdAt: 'created_at' } });
var Thing = mongoose.model('Thing', thingSchema);
var thing = new Thing();
thing.save(); // `created_at` & `updatedAt` will be included
```

Comment: Wow now i am getting millisecond varying  can u please say why it is 03:01:25 when I am trying this insertion at 8:40AM

Answer (score 0):

or, you can just use:

```
default: new Date().toISOString
```

without call the function, this is the same as:

```
default: ()=> new Date().toISOString()
```